# How to make build fail properly if npm outputs "npm ERR! not ok code 0"?

Tags: bash, npm

I have a build that every now and then goes bad. 
When that happens, I see the following print somewhere in the log:

```
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /path/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

looks to me like npm fails, but returns code 0, and the build moves on instead of fail. 
How can I make build fail when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

File a bug with npm to tell them to start returning failure for errors and wait for a fixed version.

But until then if that's your only indication of failure then you are going to need to pipe or capture the output and grep/etc. for that error message and manually exit with an error when you find it.